# JAVA - Incorporating y/n Input to Print Array list to a file

Tags: java, file, input, output, printwriter

I'm currently working on a program that is meant to store the inventory for a car dealership. I'm trying to find the correct way to print the data stored in an array list to a file when the user is prompted with a y/n option "Would you like to print the inventory to a file? (y/n)".

So far I have two separate methods. One which displays the data that I've input into the array, and one that prints the data to a file. I just need to figure out how to add the question & print to file aspect to the display method.

```
  // method to save vehicle data to a file upon exiting the program
  public static void printToFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(filename);

        String text = " Make | Model| Color| Year| Mileage\n";

        for (Automobile a : carList) {

              text += a.toCSV() + "\n"; // Separating car information with commas
        }

        pw.write(text);

        pw.flush();

        pw.close();

        System.out.println("\n Car Inventory below has been printed to " + filename + " file. \n");

        System.out.println(text);

  }

  // My method to display the data however I just need to find a way to incorporate the y/n question for printing to a file also
  public static void displayCars() { // method to display all vehicles in the list

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("--------------");
        System.out.println("Car Inventory");
        System.out.println("--------------");

        for (Automobile a : carList) {
            System.out.println(a + "\n");

            // FIND OUT HOW TO ADD y/n INPUT FOR PRINTING TO FILE
        }
  }
```

Looking to combine add a y/n question into the Display method that will ask the user if they want to print the data to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to iterate over each automobile in the list and ask the user for each whether or not they would like it added to the file, something like the following should work:

```
public static List<Automobile> displayCars() { 
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Automobile> fileItems = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("--------------");
    System.out.println("Car Inventory");
    System.out.println("--------------");

    for (Automobile a : carList) {
        System.out.println(a + "\n");
        System.out.println("Would you like to add this item to the file? (y/n)");
        String input = scnr.next();

        if (input.equals("y")) {
            fileItems.add(a);
            System.out.println("Added to file.");
        }
    }

    return fileItems;
}
```

The method now returns the list of only the automobiles that should be added to the file.

Note: I have not compiled/tested so there may be some errors.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a command line program, then you can use a Scanner to read input from the user. Something like the following would work:

```
// Creates a new Scanner that reads from standard in
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String yesNo = userInput.next(); // blocks the program until something is typed into the command line
if (yesNo.toLowerCase().equals("y")) {
    // print to file
} else {
    // continue doing something else
}
```

The .toLowerCase() isn't necessary, but I would recommend it to handle changes in case from user input.

See [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for more information.